# Ansible - when condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am very much new to ansible. I would need help in **when condition**.

Please help to correct below playbook. where as it takes input and displaying output in url.

```
    - hosts: all
      gather_facts: False
      vars_prompt:
      - name: "region"
        prompt: "Which region"
      tasks:
      - name: url_name
        set_fact:
          - url: "google.com"
            when: {{ region }} == "IN"
          - url: "facebook.com"
            when: {{ region }} == "UK"
          - url: "stackoverflow"
            when: {{ region }} == "US"
          - url: "LinkedIn"
            when: {{ region }} == "AZ"
      - debug:
          msg: url
```

Comment: Hi, welcome here. There are some obvious indentation and syntax issues. Please familiarize yourself with [conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html), and the respective module's documentation.

Comment: It is only possible to use `when` for the whole task (-> `set_fact`). \
Therefore, your snippet will not work. @Frenchy showed a nice solution how to handle your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of typing all if else, i suggest you to create a dictionnary and use the region as index:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    regions:
      IN: google.com
      US: stackoverflow        
      AZ: LinkedIn        
      UK: facebook.com 
                  
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "region"
        prompt: "Which region in {{ regions.keys() }}"
        private: no  #to hide the answer typed set yes   
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{regions}}" 

    - name: url_name
      set_fact:
        url: "{{ regions[region] }}"

    - debug:
        var: url
```

some interesting fixes:
if you add filter upper, you could accept lower or upper answer:

```
  set_fact:
    url: "{{ regions[region|upper] }}"
```